# Passing long value to Java with JNI

Tags: android, c++, qt, java-native-interface, qtandroidextras

I'm trying to pass object pointer as long from C++ code to java method through JNI to convert it back to pointer in callback later.

```
void Client::process()
{
    long thisAddress = (long)this;
    QAndroidJniObject res = activity.callObjectMethod("process", "(Ljava/lang/Long;)Ljava/lang/String;", (jlong)thisAddress);
}
```

Java function prototype is `public String process(Long clientAddr)`
and here is beauty that JVM prints to me: `Invalid indirect reference 0x5f3d9bc8 in decodeIndirectRef`.

What is wrong with this code? Or, maybe, there is another method to do what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. I managed to fix my problem by replacing Float to float using short signature "J" instead, as @Nejat suggested.

So now it looks like that
Qt:

```
QAndroidJniObject res = activity.callObjectMethod("process", "(J)Ljava/lang/String;", (jlong)thisAddress);
```

Java:

```
public String process(long clientAddr)
```

Answer (score 2):

The signature for a type of `jlong` is `J`. Also note that a C++ `long` has 32 bits, so it is equivalent to a `jint` and there is no need to use a `jlong` here. But you can also assign a `long` to a `jlong`. It would be converted automatically.

So the method call should be like :

```
QAndroidJniObject res = activity.callObjectMethod("process", "(J)Ljava/lang/String;", thisAddress);
```

Comment: That's another trick: if I use short signature, java method won't call at all. I put simple debug output into it and after such call nothing happens.